# My iPhone isn't playing WhatsApp videos sent from an android device through WhatsApp

Tags: iphone, video, error

I have an iPhone 5s and it isn't playing videos sent to me on WhatsApp, the sender is a Samsung user so maybe that's why? I can only hear the sound but the image is blank.
Is there a way to fix this or a video player than can play the videos?

Comment: what's the file format of the video sent through whatsapp ? you can only play these formats .m4v, .mp4, and .mov on your iPhone without using a third party app.

Answer (score -2):

I too had the same problem. But solved it by downloading an app called MConverter-Free medias converter.
After downloading, import the video in your app and convert it into .wmv format.
.wmv format is suitable for iPhone.

Comment: A link would be useful