# silence a WhatsApp video call on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to silence a WhatsApp video call so you don’t hear the other person. Putting the ringing volume and system volume down and I can still hear the other person on the call?

Update
I’m using both the volume buttons on the left of the phone and the volume setting found in control center when I swipe up from the bottom of the screen.

See image attached. 
[image]

Comment: iOS has several independent volume controls. Are you using the settings app to move the main one to zero or just hoping the side buttons move the setting you use? A screen shot of what you do to affect the system volume might help someone that's not user of your app. No worries - you can leave the question alone and wait for the whatsapp people to arrive and answer

Comment: Also - is this the video call you are getting? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212744/my-iphone-isnt-playing-whatsapp-videos-sent-from-an-android-device-through-what

Comment: @bmike that's more to do with videos being sent than video calls